# jQuery UI tabs and multiselect href mishandling of base tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, href, multi-select, radix

I'm trying to solve this issue brought by recent changes to the jQuery UI.
I'm using codeigniter, jquery 1.8.2., jquery UI 1.9.1.

I always put this in the head part:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

so i can have a centralized url approach for my images, ajax call and for other reasons.
the problem is, jquery UI will also use this as reference to all anchor href for all the pages. for example, if you put a jQuery UI tab in

http://www.example.com/view/users/1

the first tab will load the contents of the home page because it loads the

http://www.example.com/# path

same problem with multiselect (http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) only, the check all and uncheck all will redirect you to home page because the

```
<a href="#">
```

will take you to http://www.example.com/# instead of calling the current page js functions e.g. http://www.example.com/view/users/1#

found similar tickets:

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4941

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8637

Comment: While I do not have a solution, after reading the documentation for `base`, the behaviour of jquery ui is the same as the behaviour of modern browsers. The issue is not so much with jQeury as with your markup. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.fn.__tabs = $.fn.tabs;$.fn.tabs = function (a, b, c, d, e, f) {
var base = location.href.replace(/#.*$/, '');
$('ul>li>a[href^="#"]', this).each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', base + href);
});
$(this).__tabs(a, b, c, d, e, f);
};
```

weird. this worked for me. for the tabs.